# JavaScript in Echo php

Tags: javascript, php

hey guys can anyone help me to make this javascript code work in echo php area :/ .. please help cuz i really need this :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function countDown(secs,elem){
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" seconds";
 if(secs<1){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        element.innerHTML = '<h2>Countdown Complete!</h2>';
        element.innerHTML += '<a href="'.$url.'">Click here now</a>';
 }
    secs--;
    var timer = setTimeout ('countDown('+secs+',"'+elem+'")',1000)
}
</script>
<div id="status"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">countDown(10,"status"); </script>
```

Comment: Where is echo? Where is php? What you want to achieve here?

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up Javascript and PHP without telling the websever which one to use.

Change this line:

```
element.innerHTML += '<a href="'.$url.'">Click here now</a>';
```

to

```
element.innerHTML += '<a href="<?php echo $url ?>">Click here now</a>';
```

And ensure somewhere, before this call, that you are actually setting that php value.

Comment: WillParky93 Thanks so much it's working .. thanks a lot !!